# Why is that interior points exist only inside intervals on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I'm reading a book on real analysis that has a chapter on open sets, closed sets, limit points and compact sets (for the sake of generality, according to the author).

> If a set  $X$ has some interior point, it must have at least one open interval, then it's infinite.
>
> Every open set is an non-enumerable set.

But it seems that for having interior points, the open interval must be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ - the book does not mention the reason for that. Why is it impossible to have interior points in a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, for example?

There's a definition on interior points:

> $x \in X$ is an interior point of the set $X$ iff there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset X$. If $x\in (a,b)\subset X$, **let** $\epsilon$  **be the smallest of the positive numbers**  $x-a$ and $x-b$. Then $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subset (a,b)$ then $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset X$.

I am thinking that the bold text has something to do with it, it's impossible to know if the smallest positive number $\epsilon$ is rational or real. Is that the reason for having interior points only on intervals inside $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What book?${}{}$

Comment: $(a,b):=\{x\in \mathbb R\mid a<x<b\}$, so it seems that *everything* the text discusses is about the topological (and metric) space $\mathbb R$ and it seems that "set" is intended to mean "subset of $\mathbb R$". Of course th econclusion "Every open set is non-enumerable" is already false because $\emptyset$ is open.

Comment: i don't understand your question, if such a $\epsilon$ exist, then $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is an open interval and by the definition is in $X$! is $X$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @jouge Preciselly.

Comment: @ChrisEagle [This one](http://loja.sbm.org.br/DetProduto.aspx?id=81).

Comment: If you consider the subspace topology induced to $\mathbb{Q}$ from the usual topology of the reals, then sure, you have open sets inside the rationals. But that is kinda meaningless (you can turn any set into an open one like that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that $\Bbb{Q}$ does not have any interior points is this. Take any rational number $x$, and say we can choose $(a,b)$ about $x$ so that $x \in (a,b) \subseteq \Bbb{Q}$. Then we must have that the cardinality of $\Bbb{Q}$ be ***greater than or equal to*** the cardinality of $(a,b)$. But $(a,b)$ is uncountable being diffeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$, contradicting $\Bbb{Q}$ being countable.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that your question can be read as asking if subsets of $Q$ can have interior points when taking your overall space as $Q$, while this answer depends on having your space as $R$. Which did you mean?

Comment: I want to know why only intervals on $R$ have interior points. Also, I wasn't complaining about the downvote in my question, I was asking why someone downvoted BenjaLim's answer.

Comment: It just depends on how you define interior point. You want the definition to convey the fact that all points are completely surrounded by other points in the subset. Every point of $\mathbb Q$ has irrational points infinitely close to it, so it is in fact not *completely* surrounded by other elements of $\mathbb Q$. This is of course when discussing the standard metric-topology on $\mathbb R$ and not the subspace topology inherited by $\mathbb Q$.